# Specifying a Roboto font in Android

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to set a Roboto font variant in CSS - not working.

font-family: 'sans-serif-condensed'

I tried 'Roboto-Black' - not working also.

If I set the font-family to a font name that's in my /app/fonts folder - that works.

Answer (score 1):

To apply font variant use either css properties like `font-weight` (**bold**, normal) and `font-style` (*italic*, normal) or provide the different font variants usually created by the authors of the fonts in separate font files.
With [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto) you have 12 different made font variants like Roboto-Bold, Roboto-THin, Roboto-Medium and others. You can use them with the file name as you mentioned in your post.
e.g.
app.css

```
.rb-black {
    font-family: "Roboto-Black"
}

.rb-black-italic {
    font-family: "Roboto-BlackItalic"
}

.rb-bold {
    font-family: "Roboto-Bold"
}

.rb-medium {
    font-family: "Roboto-Medium"
}
```

Will produce the following results:

[image]

Sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/NickIliev/NativeScript-Issues-2017/tree/master/stackoverflow/robotoFont)

`font-family` in NativeScript supports three generic families as follows:

```
serif (ex. Times New Roman)
sans-serif (ex. Helvetica)
monospace (ex. Courier New)
```

So using sans-serif-condensed won't produce the expected results.

Comment: Ok - I see you added the fonts explicitly in the fonts folder. But if it's a built-in font, shouldn't that work. {N} would search the /fonts folder and then the built-in fonts?

Comment: Roboto is not build-in font for NativeScript so indeed we need to add it explicitly in the fonts folder

Comment: Roboto is a built-in font of Android...but no matter - I understand. If I use sans-serif - then does Nativescript use Roboto w/o it being in the fonts folder. It's difficult for me to tell because the font faces are similar.